# error in python when using < for comparison

Tags: python, pandas, signals, apply

I have a code that works that way as presented.
The code works perfectly when I do the comparison of > but when I do smaller < the apply function returns a df without the columns, with a column name 0 with each row a series in the cell.

```
def filtrar_tempo_candles(row):
    if pd.notna(row['Proxima_Hora']) and pd.notna(row['Hora_anterior']):
        if row['Proxima_Hora'] - row['Hora'] >= pd.Timedelta(hours=1):
            return row
        else:
            return None
    if row['Proxima_Hora'] - row['Hora'] >= pd.Timedelta(hours=1):
        return row
    
    if row['Hora_anterior'] - row['Hora'] <= pd.Timedelta(hours=1):
        return row
        
    if row['Sozinho'] ==1:
        return row


df_indice_5 = df_indice_5.loc[(df_indice_5["Diff_corr_banda"].between(10,21)) &
                                  (df_indice_5['Fechamento'] > df_indice_5['BBANDS ACIMA'])]

df_indice_5_final = df_indice_5.apply(filtrar_tempo_candles,axis=1,result_type='expand')
```

it works.

but when I reverse the sign, no

```
df_indice_5 = df_indice_5.loc[(df_indice_5["Diff_corr_banda"].between(10,21)) &
                                  (df_indice_5['Fechamento'] < df_indice_5['BBANDS ACIMA'])]



df_indice_5_final = df_indice_5.apply(filtrar_tempo_candles,axis=1,result_type='expand')
```

Comment: We have no way of telling what is going on without seeing the actual data. Maybe the result **should** be empty, aka there are not matching rows?

Comment: What do you mean "when I reverse the sign, no"? "no" is not a description of what happens. Also, you're not really reversing the sign, the opposite of > is <=, not < - you're skipping equals in your code, maybe that's what "breaks"?

Comment: The bitwise and operator `&` looks more than suspicious.